# Itext generated pdf not opening in Adobe reader?

Tags: java, server, itext, pdf-generation

I am using itext(version 5.5.4) to create a pdf file in a server. When I download the file on client and try to open it in adobe reader, it does not open and a message pops up saying that "There was an error processing a page. There was a problem reading this document(129)".

[image]

This pdf file opens in other application(like evince, foxit and google chrome) just fine. Below is the part of the code that I am using.

```
 public static String genPdfAsBase64(String orientation, JSONObject data)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    if(orientation.equals("landscape")) {
        doc = new Document(PageSize.A4.rotate(), 10f, 10f, 50f, 5f); 
    } else {
        doc = new Document();
    }
    JSONArray header = (JSONArray)data.get("header");
    JSONArray body = (JSONArray)data.get("body");

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, baos);
    TableHeader evt = new TableHeader();
    evt.setOrientation(orientation);
    writer.setPageEvent(evt);
    doc.addAuthor(AUTHOR);
    doc.open();
    Image img = Image.getInstance(Base64.decode(BASE_64_IMG));
    img.setAlignment(Image.ALIGN_MIDDLE);
    img.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
    img.scaleToFit(20f,20f);
    doc.add(img);
    Paragraph par = new Paragraph("Report", new Font(FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10));
    par.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    doc.add(par);
    doc.add(new Paragraph(" "));
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(header.size());
    table.setTotalWidth(1500);
    table.setHeaderRows(1);
    /*Header*/
    for(Object obj : header) {
        String text = (String)obj;
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text));
        cell.setBackgroundColor(headerCol);
        table.addCell(cell);
    }
    /*Body*/
    for(int i=0; i<body.size(); i++) {
        JSONArray row = (JSONArray)body.get(i);
        for(Object obj : row) {
            String text = String.valueOf(obj);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text, sansFont));
            if(i%2 != 0) {
                cell.setBackgroundColor(evenCol);
            }
            table.addCell(cell);
        }   
    }       
    doc.add(table);
    doc.close();
    byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    baos.close();
    String base64 = Base64.encodeBytes(bytes);
    return base64;
}
```

Can anyone please help?
Thanks

p.s. I have created a [sample](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W-q70jzC7amYYmsGDyHwvuJYIytggWdy/view?usp=sharing) file .

Comment: Please share the PDF in question.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't share it. Will try to create a dummy pdf.

Comment: @mkl I have added a link to a sample file.

Comment: It looks like the issue is with the `sansFont`, at least by removing it from the shared file the original issue vanished. And it looks like that font is not defined at all in your code. So please define that font inside `genPdfAsBase64` and don't re-use it across calls.

Comment: @mkl I have removed the font. It doesn’t help. Can you please tell me how did you remove the font from the pdf?

Comment: *"I have removed the font. It doesn’t help."* - Then please the updated code and sample file for further analysis. *" Can you please tell me how did you remove the font from the pdf? "* - I opened the PDF using RUPS and removed it from the resources. This obviously is not the same as fixing the code. For further analysis, therefore, update code and sample output.

Comment: @mkl thanks, but i cant share he code with you.

Comment: *"i cant share he code with you."* - ??? But *you already did share code* in your question above! I didn't ask you to share your complete code base, merely to append to your question the changes to the code there you applied when you "removed the font."

Comment: @mkl ok, i have just commented the sansFont part.

Comment: Ok. I also see in your code that you declare `Document doc` outside of `genPdfAsBase64`. As you instantiate the `Document`, open it, fill it, and close it in that method, there is no need for that, and if the class in question may concurrently be used by other requests, too, chances are that in mid-request the instance is exchanged from a separate thread. Thus, I would also advice to pull that declaration into this method as a local variable.

Comment: @mkl, hi, I removed the font from my code, and it is working properly. Earlier I must have done something wrong claiming that I had done it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason stated by @mkl above is the problem. I am using wrong fonts. I downloaded the font from [here](https://www.fontspace.com/gnu-freefont/freesans) and it is now working.

Answer (score -2):

Hi you can replace last 4 line with this. It doesn't require to close ByteArrayOutputStream before encode.

```
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes);
return base64;
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help. The pdf is opening on other viewer jusft fine. Only adobe reader it is not.